# Parse complex XML with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, xml

I am not a programming ninja, my specialties are in other things.  But I need to take a complex (and large ~.5-3mb) XML file and extract certain values from it, add HTML, and spit it back out on to a webpage.

The part that has me particularly hung up is best explained by the example below:

There are hundreds of elements that look like this:

```
<device id="1023">
```

each with a different number for their "id" attribute.

Nested inside each of those  elements are several elements like this:

```
<sensor id="34222">
```

each of those also has a different number for their "id" attribute.

Now what I need to do is two fold.  I need to go to specific

```
<device>
```

elements with a certain "id" attribute, and retrieve the value of a sub element like

```
<name>
```

Then as a separate task I need to go to specific "sensor" elements with a certain "id" attribute, and retrieve the value of a sub element like

```
<status>
```

I will have the specific "id" number for the device and sensors I need to query, so it will be statically defined. I need to grab that data so I can write it and some HTML code to some sort of variable or spit it back as the data returning from the PHP execution.

Additionally, before you even get to any of the "device"s or "sensor"s there are several tags/elements, and some of them have attributes or "id"s.  Some "device"s or "sensor"s elements have multiple tags/elements with different attribute "id" numbers.
A sample of the XML file is below.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  This has my brain all twisted around.  Thanks for any help!!

```
<bldghvac>
<bldghvac-version>14.2.10.2114+</bldghvac-version>
<options>...</options>
    <sensortree>
        <nodes>
            <probenode id="20199">
            <name>Customer 1 (123.43.66.789)</name>
            <id>20199</id>
            <url>/probenode.htm?id=20199</url>
            <tags/>
            <priority>3</priority>
            <fixed>0</fixed>
            <status_raw>3</status_raw>
            <active>true</active>

                <group id="20255">
                <name>Some Town</name>
                <id>20255</id>
                <url>/group.htm?id=20255</url>
                <tags/>
                <priority>3</priority>
                <fixed>0</fixed>
                <status_raw>3</status_raw>
                <active>true</active>

                    <group id="21717">
                    <name>Group 1</name>
                    <id>21717</id>
                    <url>/group.htm?id=21717</url>
                    <tags/>
                    <priority>3</priority>
                    <fixed>0</fixed>
                    <status_raw>3</status_raw>
                    <active>true</active>   

                        <device id="20357">
                        <summary>0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0</summary>
                        <name>Dev1 Bldg 1</name>
                        <deviceicon>vendors.png</deviceicon>
                        <id>20357</id>
                        <url>/device.htm?id=20357</url>
                        <tags>vendors</tags>
                        <priority>3</priority>
                        <fixed>0</fixed>
                        <host>172.22.37.253</host>
                        <status_raw>3</status_raw>
                        <active>true</active>

                            <sensor id="20359">
                            <name>System Uptime</name>
                            <id>20359</id>
                            <url>/sensor.htm?id=20359</url>
                            <fixed>0</fixed>
                            <status_raw>3</status_raw>
                            <status>Up</status>
                            <datamode>0</datamode>
                            <lastvalue>58 Days</lastvalue>
                            <active>true</active>
                            </sensor>

                            <sensor id="20359">
                            <name>System Uptime</name>
                            <id>20359</id>
                            <url>/sensor.htm?id=20359</url>
                            <fixed>0</fixed>
                            <status_raw>3</status_raw>
                            <status>Up</status>
                            <datamode>0</datamode>
                            <lastvalue>58 Days</lastvalue>
                            <active>true</active>
                            </sensor>
                        </device>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </probenode>
        </nodes>
    </sensortree>
</bldghvac>
```

Comment: It is possible, of course, and not that hard. But you'll have to pick an extension to do it easily : SimpleXML / DOM Document are two of them very popular and quite easy to use.

Comment: You should use this 

$xml=simplexml_load_file("name of your xml file.xml");
$xml->sensortree->...->group->device

hope this helps you. look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_string.asp

Comment: Ok great.  Do you know how I can extract just the data of, for example, the "status" element under
    <sensor id="23333">
?  I have got this working for simple XML files in testing, but not with this one.  I think it's because I don't know how to work with attributes well.  But not sure.

Comment: @platform115 The problem is that you have nested `group_id` nodes and you only provide a part of the XML. Can you give a minified structure so we can help you to target to wanted node ?

Comment: Hey Clément, if I understood you right, I was missing the closing tags.  I have added them as they appear in the XML file.

Comment: can you post your php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to access to several fields of your XML. Since it's always working the same way, I'm just showing here an example to :

Get the status of the sensor "20359" from device "20357", and the name of that device

It's all about looping (with `foreach`) over nodes when there are several of them with the same name, and check the attributes with `$elem->attributes()`

```
$group = $xml->sensortree->nodes->probenode->group->group;

$wanted_device = 20357;
$wanted_sensor = 20359;

foreach ($group->device as $device) {
  $attributes = $device->attributes();
  if ($attributes['id'] == $wanted_device) {
    $device_name = $device->name;
    foreach ($device->sensor as $sensor) {
      $attributes = $sensor->attributes();
      if ($attributes['id'] == $wanted_sensor) {
        $sensor_status = $sensor->status;
      }
    }
  }
}

echo $device_name;
echo "\n";
echo $sensor_status;
```

Output :

> Dev1 Bldg 1
>
> Up

Just let me know if you struggle to get a particular node, but that's basically how it works.